# React event: get Key AND prevent event propagation

Tags: reactjs

I have a nested list in React. The LI elements have an onClick event handler. It needs to stop propagation or else all the higher lying event handlers will fire too.

I can do this by having:

```
<li key='myKey' onClick={this.onClick}/>
```

combined with

```
onClick (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
}
```

I can also pass the key by doing:

```
<li key='myKey' onClick={this.onClick.bind(this, 'myKey'}/>
```

But how can I pass BOTH?

I have searched long but not found a way to extract the key from the event.

Comment: When you bind additional arguments, they are prepended to the normal arguments, so e.g. `onClick(key, event)`. See [`Function#bind` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: @BinaryMuse Yes!!! You made my day! If you make this an answer I can accept it as that

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<li
  key={key}
  onClick={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // invoke your onClick callback here
    this.handleOnClick(key);
  }}
/>
```